# Search a string across all columns of a query result

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I have a query, which has around 50 columns and it is subject to change.

I need to modify my SQL-DML to search a specific string across all 50 columns.

How is this possible?

```
select
  *
from
  messages a
  FULL OUTER JOIN  customers b ON a.customer_id = b.customer_id
  FULL OUTER JOIN orders c ON c.customer_id = b.customer_id
  FULL OUTER JOIN delivery_templates d ON c.billing_template_id = d.delivery_template_id

where
  product_id != '0'
  and a.hide_question = '0'
  and a.seller_id in ('2', '3', '1', '6')
  AND a.market_place_id IN (
    SELECT
      MAX(market_place_id)
    FROM
      messages
    GROUP BY
      product_id
  )
order by
  a.market_place_id desc
```

So far the best alternative seem to be

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE Col1 LIKE '%foo%' OR 
      Col2 LIKE '%foo%' OR  
      Col3 LIKE '%foo%' OR 
      Col4 LIKE '%foo%' OR 
      Col5 LIKE '%foo%' OR 
      Col6 LIKE '%foo%'
```

Comment: Related question on SE Code Review: [SQL: Search for a keyword in several columns of a table](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2364/9501)

Answer (score 1):

A database is not a fancy mechanism to grep. **This is a horrible idea don't do this ever.** That said you can convert the `row` object to a `tsvector` using Full Text Search

```
SELECT to_tsvector(to_jsonb(t)) @@ 'bar'
FROM ( VALUES ('foo','bar','baz') ) AS t(a,b,c);
```

or you can search it as if it was text.

```
SELECT t::text LIKE '%bar%'
FROM ( VALUES ('foo','bar','baz') ) AS t(a,b,c);
```